# R {spdep} Get list of neighbors from nb object

Tags: r, polygon, nearest-neighbor, r.neighbor

I want to identify the specific neighbors of each polygon within a SpatialPolygonDataFrame from `nb` object.

[image]

I know I can get the number of neighbors by polygon id by `card(nb)`, but how to get the list of the pairs? For example, something like this (in rook case):

```
id neighbors
1  NA
2  3,5
3  2,6,4
4  3,7
etc
```

My dummy data:

```
library(spdep)    # neighbours
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(dplyr)
library(spData)
library(sf)


# create simple reproductible example

r <- raster(nrow=6, ncol=6, crs = "+init=epsg:2957")
values(r) <- matrix(data = c(9,  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
                             NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                             NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                             NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1,
                             NA, NA, NA, 1, 9, 1,
                             NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1),
                    nrow = 6,
                    ncol = 6, 
                    byrow = TRUE)
```

Calculate neighbors:

```
# continuity based neighbourhood: import whole 
# shapefile, do not split it
nb <- poly2nb(polys, row.names = polys, 
                   snap = 10) # snap corrects for the gaps/slivers
```

Extract the number of neighbors (here, QUEEN case)

```
card(nb)

[1] 0 3 5 3 5 8 5 3 5 3
```

Merge data back:

```
# add number of neighbours to original polygon
polys$nb_count<- card(nb)
```

Get the count of neighbors by polygon:

```
> polys@data

   layer nb_count
1      9        0
2      1        3
3      1        5
4      1        3
5      1        5
6      9        8
7      1        5
8      1        3
9      1        5
10     1        3
```

**Which polygons are the specific neighbors?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nb` object is a ragged list, so you can either get them as elements of the list:

```
> nb[[1]]
[1] 0
> nb[[2]]
[1] 3 5 6
> nb[[3]]
[1] 2 4 5 6 7
```

showing the first polygon has no neighbours, the second one connects to 3, 5, and 6, and so on.

Or convert to a full binary adjacency matrix:

```
> mm = nb2mat(nb,zero.policy=TRUE, style="B")
> mm
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
1     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
2     0    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    0     0
3     0    1    0    1    1    1    1    0    0     0
[etc]
```

note this matrix is symmetric about the diagonal, so `mm[3,2]` is the same as `mm[2,3]` and tells you if polygon 2 is adjacent to polygon 3.

As a quick check, the sum across columns or rows of this matrix should be the same as `card`:

```
> apply(mm, 1, sum)
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 0  3  5  3  5  8  5  3  5  3 
> card(nb)
 [1] 0 3 5 3 5 8 5 3 5 3
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. I have completely forget to simply check the `nb` structure using `str(nb)` . Now it is getting clearer